# FUEL API: Best Practices for Multithreaded queries

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, fuel

I have a question:

We’re trying to implement some multithreaded queries using the Fuel API, and are curious about rate limits. Are there any best practices for this type of scenario? How many calls can we simultaneously perform without running into problems?

Thanks!